# PHP echo html using Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html

Example of the html page I'm trying to grab text from:

```
<div class="su-box-content su-clearfix">tim and jake <strong> meeting at 1 am <span style="color: #00ff00;">finished</span></strong>
</div>
```

Instead of it echoing "time and jake meeting at 1 am done" I'd like to echo the html too so it becomes "time and jake **meeting at 1 am** done"

I'm using the library from: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: which php library you are using ? PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser ? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I'm using the one you mentioned above. @Mit.agile

Comment: `$date=$html->find('div[class=su-box-title]');`

Comment: @splash58 This fixed the error however now it returns Trying to get property of non-object at this statement. echo $date->plaintext;

Comment: can u **print_r($date);** ? , it will give you better idea.

Comment: i think, you need set an index, something as `$date[0]->plaintext;`

Comment: @splash58 That fixed it! Thank you so much sir!

Comment: @splash58 I updated my post, is there any way to accomplish this with the simple html dom parser?